# Predict value for multiple columns in Natural language processing

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-analysis, data-processing, nlp

I have a dataset of emails contains 4 fields. One is exact number of people, second is date, person need laptop or not, person interested in cafeteria or not. And, want to predict values for all these features using natural language processing. So, how can I create the dataset and apply natural language processing on that?

Comment: You want to predict all 4 values? How much data do you have?

Comment: @ウィエム Thnaks for reply. I have 100 emails. but i want to know how can i do this?.. if need more data, i can increase it.